# Search results count not updated when deleting items

Tags: sxa, solr, content-search

I am using Sitecore 9.0.2. and SXA 1.8.

I am facing a strange issue when I delete an item. The search results that returns this item is retrieved with the old count (including the deleted item) although the item itself is not included any more.

After checking the Solr indexes, it appears that the item still exists in the index and therefore it is returned in the search result count.

When using checklist filters, the same issue occurs as well. When deleting an item of any type, the count of that type still contains the item although the item itself is deleted.

This issue only disappears after rebuilding the index. Is there a way to solve this issue?

Comment: Please check if the issue disappears after you publish the parent of the item which has been deleted. The idea is that , publish on end , starts the indexing process.

Answer (score 1):

I had this bug in SXA 1.7.1. The issue was that deleted items did not get removed from the index (apparently the SXA implemention was missing a null check).

The result of the bug is indeed that items do not get removed from the index, unless you do a rebuild of the sxa index. This makes the count wrong (as that goes by the index) but not the results as SXA is fetching the items to display those and it won't find that item anymore in the database.

You need to contact Sitecore Support to get a patch for this issue.

Apparently it got fixed in SXA 1.9 - in the release notes you can find:

> SxaItemCrawler does not remove deleted documents from the
>   sitecore_sxa_web_index during publishing operations.  TFS no 304700